# Snapshot listener doesn't work after I initialize him in onCreate. Firestore android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this Snapshot listener that checks when a chat model is added or modified I want it to give it to me, but the snapshot listener works only when the activity starts and from there, it stops working. The problem is that it doesn't even goes to the onEvent()...
this is the function where I initialize the snapshot listener.
the function triggered in the onCreate function.

```
private void addChatRoomSnapshotListener() {
    chatRoomsListener = chatsQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if (error != null) {
                error.printStackTrace();

                return;
            }
            for (DocumentChange change : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                switch (change.getType()) {
                    case ADDED:
                        ChatModel chatModel = change.getDocument().toObject(ChatModel.class);
                        chatModel.setId(change.getDocument().getId());
                        chats.add(chatModel);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case MODIFIED:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "modifeid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Handle modified document
                        ChatModel modifiedChat = change.getDocument().toObject(ChatModel.class);
                        modifiedChat.setId(change.getDocument().getId());
                        // Find the position of the modified chat in the list
                        int modifiedIndex = findChatIndexById(modifiedChat.getId());
                        if (modifiedIndex != -1) {
                            // Replace the existing chat with the modified chat
                            chats.remove(modifiedChat);
                            chats.add(0, modifiedChat);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

here is how I remove the snapshot listener.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Remove the snapshot listener to avoid memory leaks
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "listener removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (chatRoomsListener != null) {
        chatRoomsListener.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops working"? If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: The app does not crashes.
The snapshot listener does not get triggered when I add an item or item is modified... it doesn't even gets to the onEvent function I put there at the start of the function a toast that will tell me if the onEvent function is triggered and it only triggers once when the actvitystarts

Comment: Where are you calling this `addChatRoomSnapshotListener()` method from?

Comment: @AlexMamo from the onCreate function

Comment: Show us that code.

Comment: @AlexMamo I fixed the issue, I fixed it by using Firebase indexes for some reason it worked when I added it.

Answer (score 0):

better you use childEventListner() insted of valueaddedlistner() .try once

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are removing the listener **onPause** and not registering it again. Because **onCreate** is called once but **onPause** is can be called several times. Try this: Either remove the listener **onDestroy** or register the listener **onResume**.

Answer (score 0):

To make the snapshot work with query you will have to add firebase index to your query
You will see this in your logcat
[image]

Just click the link and it will add your index.
This solved my problem.